# How can I retrieve a Pokémon from the Dream World after it has closed down?

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

In Pokémon Black 2, I sent a Pokémon to the Dream World back when it was still active. When I try to wake it up using Game Sync now, the game just tells me that the service has shut down.

Is there any way to get it back? I would be surprised if the Pokémon's data is actually deleted from the game card when Game Sync is used, so my guess is that it's just a matter of waking it up.

I remember there being a backup way of getting a Pokémon out of the Pokéwalker by pressing a specific button combination (in case the Pokéwalker ran out of power or was lost). Is there maybe somthing similar for the Dream World?

Comment: Have you tried the [Entralink](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/Entralink) ?

Comment: @dly I checked all the characters in the Entralink and none of them seemed to be able to do anything helpful.

Comment: If it'snot there and you can't wake it up the usual way (there was a fail safe mechanism as you already suggested) I guess the grace period is over. The fail safe is or was that it should still be possible to sync even with the service being down. This info is too vague to be a valid answer, though. Maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this since the Wi-Fi for Black & White 1 and Black & White 2 was shut down, which is sad but true and simple